# Increase value of duplicate element value within array

Tags: c#

I have some C# code. The purpose of this code is to produce a list of integers, have their values tested to see if they are duplicate entries values, and alter any duplicate entries to be unique if they occur within the list.

```
static int oldHash, newHash; // used if collision true, // renews current hash
static Boolean Uniqiue; // only update variables? 

public static int collisionHandling(int oldHash, bool unique)
{
    if (!unique)
    {
        newHash = oldHash + 1;
        return newHash;
    }
    else
    {
        newHash = oldHash;
        return 0;
    }
}

public static int hash(int value) {
    return value +1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> intLst = new List<int>(20);

    intLst.Add(1);
    intLst.Add(1);
    intLst.Add(1);

    int tst = 0;

    while (tst <= intLst.Count - 1)
    {
        int hashResult = hash(intLst[tst]);

        if (intLst.Contains(hashResult))
        {
            int collisionResult = collisionHandling(hashResult, false);
            Console.WriteLine(collisionResult);
        }

        tst += 1;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output of this application is

```
3
3
3
```

Great, I have added values to a new list and adjusted them. However, I have not assured a unique value within my list. **How do I do this?**

The principle is without using a hash table, I must create one. Hash tables must have unique keys, and therefore duplicate attempts (collisions) are to be handled. I do not wish to remove the hash key, I wish for it to be handled in the form of making it unique. Therefore, my approach should be similar to `value = value + Random.Next()` as this would have a more accurate outcome as appose to 'value = value +1'. However, this doesn't ensure a unique entry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq `Distinct` to provide a set from your list. (i.e remove duplicates from your list).

Then add new numbers as duplicates items are removed.

```
var list = ...;
var unique = list.Distinct().ToList();
var random = new Random();

for(int i = unique.Count(); i < list.Count(); i++)
{            
    int r;
    do
    {
        r = random.Next();
    } while(unique.Contains(r))
    unique.Add(r);
}

// unique is the result you want
list = unique;
```

Note that this method is not stable. that means it does not guarantee to keep the order of your items. also this can turn into infinite loop in theory.